# Validating files and returning errors messages/boolean values

Tags: java, exception-handling

I am writing simple file validator for my java ee app and I am stack with my class api. I need specific error descriptions, but also I would like to have boolean values indicating whether file is valid or not. Please give me some hints how to do it 'smart'.

```
package pl.poznan.put.ims.business.attachments;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

import pl.poznan.put.ims.business.entities.Attachment;
import pl.poznan.put.ims.business.exceptions.AttachmentValidationException;
import pl.poznan.put.ims.settings.IFileSystemSettings;

public class AttachmentValidator implements IAttachmentValidator 
{   
      IFileSystemSettings messageSettings;
      private List<String> errors;

    @Inject
    public AttachmentValidator(IFileSystemSettings messageSettings)
    {
        this.messageSettings = messageSettings;
        this.errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(List<Attachment> attachments) throws AttachmentValidationException
    {
        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
            validate(attachment);       
        }

        if(attachments.size() > messageSettings.getMaxFilesCount())
            errors.add("Attachments max number exceeded.");

        if(!errors.isEmpty())
            throw new AttachmentValidationException(errors);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(Attachment attachment)
    {
        boolean isValid = validateLimitExceeded(attachment);
        isValid &= validateNull(attachment);

        return !isValid;
    }

    private boolean validateLimitExceeded(Attachment attachment)
    {           
        boolean exceeded = attachment.getFileSize() > messageSettings.getMaxFileSize(); 
        if(exceeded)
            errors.add("Max file size limit exceeded. File: " + attachment.getFileDisplayName() + ". Size: "+ attachment.getFileSize()/1024/1024 + "MB.");

        return exceeded;
    }

    private boolean validateNull(Attachment attachment)
    {
        if(attachment == null) {
            errors.add("No attachment.");   
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getErrors()
    {
        return errors;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTotalMaxFilesSize() {
        return messageSettings.getMaxFilesCount() * messageSettings.getMaxFileSize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- The `boolean validate(...)` method never returns `false` so it should be `void` method.
- I'd pass immutable `ValidationResult` objects to the clients. The clients could check the results and could signal to their clients if there is an error or prints the messages etc.
- I'd omit the `&=` operator, it's really hard to read.
- `getTotalMaxFilesSize()` should be in the `FileSystemSettings` class. (Feature or data envy smell.)

After a few refactoring steps the following came out:

`AttachmentValidatorService.java`

```
import java.util.List;

public interface AttachmentValidatorService {

    ValidationResult validate(List<Attachment> attachments);

    ValidationResult validate(Attachment attachment);

    long getTotalMaxFilesSize();
}
```

`ValidationResult.java`

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable;

@Immutable
public class ValidationResult {

    private final List<String> errors;

    public ValidationResult(final List<String> errors) {
        checkNotNull(errors, "errors cannot be null");
        this.errors = new ArrayList<String>(errors);
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        if (errors.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(errors);
    }

    // If lots of the clients use this
    //  public void checkErrors() {
    //      if (!isValid()) {
    //          throw new ...
    //      }
    //  }
}
```

`AttachmentValidatorServiceImpl`:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AttachmentValidatorServiceImpl implements
        AttachmentValidatorService {
    private final FileSystemSettings messageSettings;

    public AttachmentValidatorServiceImpl(
            final FileSystemSettings messageSettings) {
        this.messageSettings = checkNotNull(messageSettings,
                "messageSettings cannot be null");
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(final List<Attachment> attachments) {
        final AttachmentValidator attachmentValidator = new AttachmentValidator(
                messageSettings, attachments);
        return attachmentValidator.getValidationResult();
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(final Attachment attachment) {
        return validate(Collections.singletonList(attachment));
    }

    @Override
    public long getTotalMaxFilesSize() {
        return messageSettings.getMaxFilesCount()
                * messageSettings.getMaxFileSize();
    }
}
```

`AttachmentValidator.java`

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AttachmentValidator {

    private final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final FileSystemSettings messageSettings;

    public AttachmentValidator(
            final FileSystemSettings messageSettings,
            final List<Attachment> attachments) {
        this.messageSettings = checkNotNull(messageSettings,
                "messageSettings cannot be null");
        checkNotNull(attachments, "attachments cannot be null");
        for (final Attachment attachment : attachments) {
            validate(attachment);
        }

        validateSize(attachments);
    }

    private void validate(final Attachment attachment) {
        validateNull(attachment);
        validateLimitExceeded(attachment);
    }

    private void validateSize(final List<Attachment> attachments) {
        if (attachments.size() > messageSettings.getMaxFilesCount()) {
            errors.add("Attachments max number exceeded.");
        }
    }

    private void validateLimitExceeded(final Attachment attachment) {
        if (attachment == null) {
            return;
        }
        final int fileSize = attachment.getFileSize();
        final boolean exceeded = fileSize > messageSettings
                .getMaxFileSize();
        if (exceeded) {
            final String fileDisplayName = attachment
                    .getFileDisplayName();
            final int fileSizeInMegaBytes;
            if (fileSize == 0) {
                fileSizeInMegaBytes = 0;
            } else {
                fileSizeInMegaBytes = fileSize / 1024 / 1024;
            }
            final String errorMsg = "Max file size limit exceeded. File: "
                    + fileDisplayName
                    + ". Size: "
                    + fileSizeInMegaBytes + "MB.";
            errors.add(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void validateNull(final Attachment attachment) {
        if (attachment == null) {
            errors.add("No attachment.");
        }
    }

    public ValidationResult getValidationResult() {
        return new ValidationResult(errors);
    }

}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.